# Articles on Medium and Resume/CV

Tags: publications, cv

How can one objectively leverage their articles written on Medium in a resume/CV for an employer or possibly even for position in an academic institution as a lecturer?

The point of this question is that I have been recently encourage by my professors to create blogs particularly on Medium in regards to my Computer Science, or Data Science endeavors. Is the point of it just to leverage knowledge communication both written and verbal or is it possibly to take initiative to create knowledge base articles for an employer to help company growth?

Any insight into how one can objectively leverage their articles written on Medium in a resume/CV for anyone.

Comment: I don't think you can objectively leverage anything on a resume, resumes are judged subjectively. But this question is kind of strange, is your goal to pack in as much corporate buzzspeak as possible? What are you actually trying to do, in direct language?

Comment: Did you run this through chatGPT before asking?

Answer (score 3):

I'll state upfront that my field isn't computer science but mechanical engineering. So take everything with a grain of salt.

A resume should be short. Nobody wants to read them to begin with, and nowadays computers do the initial passes for everyone. So it is only looking for programmatically specific details. There is no room for "fluff" additions like blog posts, Medium articles, etc. Only put the stuff that is tangible and directly related to what you are applying for: education, work experience, volunteering (shows being a good person and that money isn't the only thing that matters), and a brief summary. But that's about it.

A CV on the other hand can have a lot more stuff, since they usually have no set lengths. While you could put these Medium articles on it, it would be hard for someone to get an understanding of what it means. Additionally I would caution from putting "individual articles" as individual line items on your CV. It can be seen as padding your CV and is usually more detrimental than beneficial. Perhaps what you can do is add some category like "volunteering" or similar. Then just write a brief thing about writing posts/articles on Medium and a brief description of what you've written in the past (like a two sentence summary total of all the articles you've ever written). And then just include a URL link to your main Medium page or whatever. That way you aren't seen as padding your CV, but include something that you have worked on that a potential boss (beyond the standard HR hiring people) may be able to investigate. It would include the full list of what you've then written for them to see and if they wanted to they could get a better idea of your skills and knowledge as an employee.

Best of luck.